# Magento : Call to a member function count() on a non-object

Tags: magento

When i add a subcategory in Magento, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\cariocawear_new\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Navigation.php on line 324
```

This is the function in which line 324 is:

```
public function drawImgItem($category, $level = 0, $last = false)
{
   $html = '';
   $categoryName = '';
   if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
      return $html;
   }

   $children = $category->getChildren();
   $hasChildren = $children && $children->count(); <-- This is line 324 which cause error
   $html.= '<li';
   if ($hasChildren) {
       $html.= ' onmouseover="toggleMenu(this,1)" onmouseout="toggleMenu(this,0)"';
   }

   /* snipped by editor for being superfluous */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an error in that code as the function $category->getChildren() normally returns a string and not an object.

I think you should be able to make it working when replacing the code on line 323 for the following, but **I have not tested it!**.

```
$children = $category->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in', 
        explode(',', $category->getChildren())));
```

Comment: Now get this error There has been an error processing your request SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: I checked and you're right, it should be 'entity_id'; I modified the snippet.